# client_max_body_size is not working in kubernetes docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

We have different pod for different apps like for node app have diffenent pod and UI app have different pod, UI app is running in nginx server pod. we are accessing the apis using service and that we config in nginx config file. we are not able to upload the 2mb file size from UI, getting the 413 status code error.

413 Request Entity Too Large
413 Request Entity Too Large
nginx/1.17.10

We  have added the client_max_body_size in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf default.conf in server directive
server {

```
client_max_body_size 200M;

location / {
    client_max_body_size 200M;
    client_body_buffer_size    100M;
}
```

}

same code is working without docker container.
Technologies Used

1. UI -  Reactjs - Axios - hosted in nginx server
2. Nodejs
3. kubernetes
4. docker
5. SSL
6. GCP

Comment: Have you executed `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload` after changing the config?

Comment: What address does the react app use to connect to the API? Are you sure that traffic passes through the UI nginx instance?

Comment: @OhHiMark Yes, we have docker container that reload the ngnix for every new deployment of the code

Comment: @Matt yes api end poins is working fine, we are able to upload the below 1 mb file size.

Comment: Is the API endpoint via an ingress definition?

Comment: i.e. is the api endpoint different to the UI endpoint the react app is served from.

Comment: @Matt, no api endpoint rediect in UI pod nginx, not in ingress like below 

location /backendapi/ {

    proxy_pass http://servicename:3005/;

    }

Comment: @Balaji What are you using in order to reach your app?